# How does gravity affect light although it's massless?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, visible-light, photons, mass

I'm doing a school project and my question is, how does gravity affect light  although it's massless?

Comment: The answer to the linked post though has a Newtonian flavour, which is not correct. I tried to add my own answer to that post...